# how to hide text in image Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image I want to hide some text in it

I think I should get the bitplanes as follows:

```
a=imread('insect.gif');

[m n]=size(a);

for i=1:m,
    for j=1:n,
        b8(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),128);
        b7(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),64);
        b6(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),32);
        b5(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),16);
        b4(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),8);
        b3(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),4);
        b2(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),2);
        b1(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),1);
    end
end
```

so that I have first bit in "b1",second bit in "b2",third bit in "b3",....

```
s='class is good'
h=dec2bin(s,8)
```

it will give me my text each character in 8 bits I think I should hide my text in the LSB of the matrix of the image but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an byte image (8bit), then lets look at the first 3 encoded bytes or 24 pixels.
Lets also assume we want to hide the values 255, 1, and 12.

### BEFORE ENCODING 3 values

```
  MSB----LSB
1: 00000000  
2: 00000000
3: 00000000
4: 00000000
5: 00000000
6: 00000000
7: 00000000
8: 00000000

9: 00000000
10: 00000000
11: 00000000
12: 00000000
13: 00000000
14: 00000000
15: 00000000
16: 00000000

17: 00000000
18: 00000000
19: 00000000
20: 00000000
21: 00000000
22: 00000000
23: 00000000
24: 00000000
```

### AFTER ENCODING 3 values

```
  MSB----LSB
1: 00000001 
2: 00000001
3: 00000001
4: 00000001
5: 00000001
6: 00000001
7: 00000001
8: 00000001

9: 00000000
10: 00000000
11: 00000000
12: 00000000
13: 00000000
14: 00000000
15: 00000000
16: 00000001

17: 00000000
18: 00000000
19: 00000000
20: 00000000
21: 00000001
22: 00000001
23: 00000000
24: 00000000
```

So you should see that all you need to do is make sure the LSB for each pixel is 0 or 1. 
(i.e. you should only need  `b1(i,j)=bitand(a(i,j),1);` as changing the more significant bits may noticeably alter the image)

```
function pixVal = setPixel(pixVal, zeroOne)

   isOdd = mod(pixVal,2);

  if zeroOne == 1
    if ~isOdd 
       pixVal = pixVal +  1;
    end
  else 
    if isOdd
       pixVal = pixVal - 1;
    end
  end

end    



function arr = setTextInArr( arr, text )

 %convert text to binary
 lsb = dec2bin(text,8)';

 for i=1:numel(lsb)
    val = arr(i);
    val = setPixel(val, str2num(lsb(i)));
    arr(i) = val;
 end

end
```

### encode "hi" in small image

```
>> img = zeros(8,16, 'uint8')

img =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

>> s = 'hi'

s =

hi

>> encImg = setTextInArr(img,s)

encImg =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [LSB STEGANOGRAPHY](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11813-lsb-steganography) submission on the File Exchange.

The codes are open and it's exactly what you need.

Comment: yes but I didn't understand it I wanted to do it myself with this method

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches actually:

The first one is hiding data an image, when the data and the image has nothing in common and usually referred as 'steganography'.

The second one is embedding annotative data, when the data describes the image. In this case the data and the image has tight spatial relations.

What You are referring is called 'bit plane modification'. You can check the Web for quality requirements, but in most cases it's almost save to alter up to 4 bits in every byte (we used https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/iwssim/ for quality measurement).

Please also pay attention to the colour space transformations, as image is almost never stored in RGB colour space.